# How to automatically print all parameter values of Java function at runtime

Tags: java, variables, reflection, runtime, reusability

I want to print automatically all the parameter values of my functions at runtime.

Just imagin that I have the following two methods:

```
public void doAction(String firstParam, String SecondParam) {
    Util.printAllParameter(this);
}

public void doAction(String firstParam) {
    Util.printAllParameter(this);
}
```

If I call to this functions:

doAction("a", "b"); --> Desired result: Print "a, b"

doAction("a"); --> Desired result: Print "a"

I don't want something like this (This is not reusable, it is static):

```
System.out.println(firstParam + "," + SecondParam);
```

I need a reusable method that I can use in different functions with different number of parameter. I want to call a function like "Util.printAllParameter()" and then print all the parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't think something like that is possible. You can't get a handle of a "current method" as far as I know.

Comment: If you use Spring frameworks, perhaps you can implement this by AOP. By the way, "call a function like `Util.printAllParameter()`" is not "automatically".

Comment: @Amongalen You can throw/catch an exception, and then inspect its stack trace. But that is a really expensive operation which you absolutely cant use for tracing like this. And of course, it is also not reliable, as there is no guarantee that an exception really contains a stack trace (when overburdened with too many exceptions, the JVM might start to drop stack traces)

Comment: Just for the record: dropping questions here, to then walk away and not come back for hours ... isn't really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple utility method that like:

```
public void trace(String methodName, Object... args) {
```

that then inspects all the arguments and prints a nice string for you.

But you have that explicit passing of the method name as string, which can't be avoided. Yes, theoretically, one call create a stack trace by throwing/catching an exception, and deduce the method name, but that is a real performance killer, which you absolutely can't do for ordinary tracing that is supposed to happen millions of time per day.

So: there are no "built-in" mechanisms in the Java language to get you there. No "macros" or some sort of "templating" to just "pull" such behavior into your production code without doing it explicitly.

But there is the concept of "Aspect Oriented Programming". Meaning: you have *another* tool that modifies your production code, for example to automatically add such trace statements, as a part of the build/compile process.

Certain technology stacks, for example [spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html) might come with such technology.

If you are not using such frameworks, you would have to "add" something like that to your setup.

Answer (score 0):

To do it generally would require rewriting the bytecode (probably with a Java Agent, or library using it) or the source code.

The way do it without hacking the code is to use an interface and a `Proxy`. Interfaces are often suggested, but Java gets in the way with its old fashioned, super verbose syntax.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

// Gratuitous use of new fangled record feature and streams.
record TraceInvocation(PrintStream out) {
    public <T> T trace(Class<T> type, T target) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(target);
        return type.cast(Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            type.getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[] { type },
            (proxy, method, args) -> {
                // Apparently args can be null. Ffs.
                out.println(
                    (target==null ? type.getSimpleName() : escape(target))+
                    "."+method.getName()+
                    // There's probably a better way without {}.
                    "("+(args==null ? "" : String.join(", ", 
                        Stream.of(args)
                            .map(TraceInvocation::escape)
                            .toArray(String[]::new)
                    ))+")"
                );
                return method.invoke(target, args);
            }
        ));
    }
    // Don't even think about allowing log injection.
    // (Okay, weird syntax.)
    private static String escape(Object object) {
        // I am not a fan of streams.
        int[] escaped = String.valueOf(object).codePoints().flatMap(cp ->
            (cp == '\\' || cp == '.' || cp == ',') ?
                IntStream.of('\\', cp)             :
            (' ' <= cp && cp <= '~'              ) ?
                IntStream.of(cp)                   :
            ("\\"+/*(int)*/cp+"\\").codePoints()
        ).toArray();
        return new String(escaped, 0, escaped.length);
    }
}
```

Use as:

```
    CharSequence cs = new TraceInvocation(System.err)
        .trace(CharSequence.class, "Scunthorpe");
    cs.subSequence(4, 10).length(); // No log for length
    cs.charAt(2);
    cs.length();
```

Possible variation include filtering which methods to display, logging return values/exceptions, alternative to `toString` and tracing returned values.

I found this approach really useful when dealing with sending and receiving a stream in a proprietary format.

Comment: I think you should mention "requires java 14 because *record*" prominently. But nice approach. Although this directly couples your tracing aspect with production code, and woha dynamic proxies. Wondering about the performance impacts of this.

Comment: @GhostCat But 14 is the current LTS version. It's about future proofing the answer, and gratuitous use of features - the biggest advantage of streams is to show off on the internet. Even on 14 it does require the enabling new features palaver. / Performance: If you are doing the I/O who cares. I don't think it's terrible for anything other than trivial methods. There will be a more efficient way with `MethodHandle`s, but I can't be bothered with that mess.

Comment: A large fraction of the professional world is still way older than java 14. And that wont change for years I guess. Same regarding performance: any real world app might be doing 100K+ of trace calls per minute. Nothing that involves proxies or method handles is up to that.